# Special types of Sasaki manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

i have a question to special cases of Sasaki-manifolds. Let $(M, g, \xi, \eta, \Phi)$ a Sasaki-manifold.

In special case maybe $M=S^{2m+1} \cong \mathbb{C}^{m+1}$. This is a Sasaki manifold. But what is $\Phi$?

Analogous: Let $M=\mathbb{R}^{2m+1}$, it is also Sasaki, but what is $\xi$ or $\Phi$?

Thanks and best regards
Ronald

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried reading the Wikipedia page for Sasakian manifolds?  Does that not providethe information you're looking for? You haven't told us what your notation is supposed to mean so your question isn't clear.